# How to overlay UI elements in Android

Tags: android

I created a very simple flashlight app for my own use some time back - one button taking up the entire screen, and when clicked it changes the background from black to white (or back again) while also keeping the screen awake when "on"/white.  I'm now trying to add a seekbar near the bottom of the app to control screen brightness, but I still want the entire screen to show black or white and I want the seekbar to be visible at all times.  I'm using a Constraint Layout.

I tried setting elevation to 2dp on the seekbar.  The seekbar was initially visible and I could adjust its value, but when I clicked on the button it then went away.  In my searches so far I haven't found any other ways to address it. Is there something I'm overlooking or a better way to go about it?

Edit: Here's the XML of my layout.  Sorry for not responding sooner.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/backgroundButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:onClick="changeBackground"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@android:color/black" />

    <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:elevation="2dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="64dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
            android:progressTint="#EE0323D1"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is essentially what I'm trying to get it to look like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VwyV.png)

Comment: Can you post your XML here? we can help you better then.

Comment: [mcve] [howtoask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    boolean flashlightEnabled = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

        final View flashlight = findViewById(R.id.flashlight);
        flashlight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (flashlightEnabled) {
                    v.setBackgroundColor(0xFF000000);
                } else {
                    v.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
                }
                flashlightEnabled = !flashlightEnabled;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/flashlight"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    tools:context=".TestActivity">

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you!  I hadn't realized that the layout could be used as a button.  This worked great!